# Having trouble copying directory from NFS mount in Java

Tags: java, linux, nfs

I've been trying to copy a directory recursively from an NFS mount to the local file system in Java. I first tried using [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29) in Apache Utils. Sadly, it didn't copy recursively (walking through sub-directories, etc.) so I had to go back to the drawing board. I heard that some of those operations are "finicky" when they are cross-device. I was then suggested to try and use linux commands, so I tried doing so:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder()
                    .command("cp -R " + source.getAbsolutePath() + " " + dest.getAbsolutePath())
                    .start();

process.waitFor();
```

That sadly threw a response of "no such file or directory", I slapped on some debug on there and tried again. Even though I got "no such file or directory", my debug stated that both the source and destination directories exist, as well as after checking manually if they exist.

Comment: If either path has spaces you might run into problems. While it's a bit... icky to do so, you could add quotes to surround each path argument. I could see that causing no such file or directory errors. Alternatively, escape spaces and other special characters. Still, I'd find something better than using commands.

Comment: There are no spaces in the directories or files.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I decided to write my own implementation and oddly enough it worked. Sadly, I have little-to-no knowledge why this worked over FileUtils. Here is what I wrote:

```
private void copy(File source, File destination) throws IOException {
    if (source.isDirectory()) {
        if (!destination.exists()) {
            destination.mkdir();
        }

        if (destination.isFile()) {
            destination.delete();
            destination.mkdir();
        }

        for (File src : source.listFiles()) {
            File dest = new File(destination, src.getName());

            copy(src, dest);
        }
    } else {
        destination.createNewFile();

        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(source);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int l;

        while ((l = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, l);
        }

        input.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```